# Change master label of lighting component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, label

I need to change the label of a lightning component. By label of lightning component I mean the name of the component you read in the app builder.

With LWC I can edit the file component.js-meta.xml and set the  tag, but with the normal aura component I can't find a way. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, add Design to your component in Developer Console and set the following code there:

```
<design:component label="new label" />
```